# Análisis factorial de datos no paramétricos

Tags: r

Estoy analizando datos de un diseño factorial completo 3X3 de la siguiente forma:

```
aovN <-aov(y ~ x + z + x:z + Bloque , data = A)
anova(aovN)
summary(aovN)
aovNb<-aov(y~Tratamiento+Bloque, data = A)
anova(aovNb)
summary(aovNb)
```

Dándome resultados de este tipo:

```
Response: y
             Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)  
Tratamiento  8  492.67   61.58  0.5283 0.81849  
x            2  198.22   99.11  0.8502 0.44574  
z            2   29.56   14.78  0.1268 0.88181  
Bloque       2  758.22  379.11  3.2522 0.06528 .
x:z          4  264.89   66.22  0.5681 0.68948  
Residuals    16 1865.11  116.57
```

Luego hacia una prueba de Tukey del paquete agricolae.

El problema es que un grupo de estos datos no es paramétrico y quisiera hacer un analisis que me pudiera mostrar los efectos individuales y la interacción entre ellos y luego desglosarlos con una prueba post-hoc como la de Tukey en R.
¿Qué procedimiento podría usar?

Dejo una muestra de los datos:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/kz87vgtkyj0u2ho/Duda.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: Germán, te pregunta es muy interesante, pero me parece que excede la temática del sitio (Programación), yo investigaría alguno de estos tests: https://www.statmethods.net/stats/nonparametric.html, creo que el de Kruskal Wallis es uno de los más mencionados como equivalentes a ANOVA, pero esto tómalo con "pinzas", mi conocimiento es más de programación que de estadística. Suerte.

Comment: Patricio, es verdad que puedo hacer un analisis de Kruskal Wallis o de Firedman, pero haciendo cualquiera de ellos pierdo el sentido del factorial y no puedo medir la interacción entre factores, que en este caso en concreto es de gran importancia.
Dejo la pregunta pos si justo alguien conoce algún test que no sea tan común y me pueda ayudar.
Muchas gracias por responder!!

Answer (score 0):

V.test: analoga a una prueba de significancia. descarta factores no asociados significativamente con un eje factorial determinado